# Looking for a small rectangular non-rechargeable battery

Tags: batteries, battery-charging

I'm looking for an off-the-shelf non-rechargeable battery that has a similar dimension to the battery found here: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/731. Ideally, the battery would be rectangular to fit into our form factor, but I can't seem to find anything of this nature. I'm looking at coin-cell batteries, but the round form-factor breaks our design.

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Comment: I hope for your customer's sake the battery lasts a very long time.

Comment: Did the battery you previously use go obsolete or is this a new design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the battery industry the following terms are used:

Rectangular batteries => prismatic.
Non rechargeable batteries => primary cells/batteries.

Many on alibaba.

Comment: thanks, that helps, though I can't seem to find a tiny non-rechargeable.

Comment: tiny being such a precise word ... here is one. http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/1246272190/3_6v_primary_lithium_battery_rechargeable.html